# Creating DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, dataframe

I have the following question:
Create a function that accepts two parameters: a pandas dataframe and a list of column names.

The function should return a new dataframe that contains only the columns listed in `col_names`.
Parameters:

```
df -- a pandas DataFrame
col_names -- list; a list of column names from df
```

Returns: pandas `DataFrame`; a subset of `df` with only columns listed in `col_names`.

As follows

```
def df_subset(df, col_names):
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Super easy, barely an inconvenience:

```
def df_subset(df, col_names):
    return df[col_names]
```

That function will return a data frame with only the columns specified from the original data frame.

The list needs to have the name of the wanted columns, but if you want to use indexes instead:

```
def df_subset(df, col_indexes):
    return df.iloc[:, col_indexes]
```